# Importing css-element-queries to an angular 6 application

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I'm trying to install and use the [css-element-queries library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-element-queries).

For installing, I used the following command:

```
npm i css-element-queries
```

After that, I tried to import the class `ResizeSensor` from the library like this:

```
import { ResizeSensor } from 'css-element-queries';
```

But the compiler retrieves the following error:

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'css-element-queries'.
>   'c:/PrjNET/Elevation3/FW/4.00/Mainline/Framework/Development/Client/ElevationJS/ngcore/node_modules/css-element-queries/index.js'
>   implicitly has an 'any' type.   Try `npm install
>   @types/css-element-queries` if it exists or add a new declaration
>   (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'css-element-queries';

Based on the error message, I tried to run the following npm command:

```
npm install @types/css-element-queries
```

But the compiler retrieved the following error:

> npm ERR! code E404 npm ERR! 404 Not Found:
>   @types/css-element-queries@latest

How can I import the css-element-queries library?

Answer (score 3):

I don't use Angular, but I just ran into importing ResizeSensor into a typescript based application. I don't know when css-element-queries added ResizeSensor.d.ts, but it is part of the package now.

However, that file is incorrect. I have filed an issue on gitHub for it. Yesterday I did some investigation on how to get it imported and ended up reading about the different module types and how to create a typings file in the [typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html).

This led me to the proper way to define the typings file for ResizeSensor. Basically take the one from the github repository and change the export line from:

```
export default ResizeSensor;
```

to

```
export = ResizeSensor;
```

then you can use this as your import:

```
import ResizeSensor = require('Libs/css-element-queries/ResizeSensor');
```

Your path to css-element-queries will be different because you wont be able to pull it from npm until the package maintainer fixes the .d.ts file.

Here is a [link to the github issue](https://github.com/marcj/css-element-queries/issues/263).

Comment: Just so everyone knows, issue above has been merged and importing in typescript works now.

Answer (score 0):

While there isn't typings package yet, I'm able to use the `css-element-queries` package using these imports:

```js
import * as ElementQueries from 'css-element-queries/src/ElementQueries';
import * as ResizeSensor from 'css-element-queries/src/ResizeSensor';
```

Atom still gives info warnings about not being able to find a declaration file, but it still works. Hope this helps!

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I trying to get it to work for ElementQueries.